# Anyone knows a good tutorial to learn how to create install profile?

Tags: distributions

I just want to create an 'install profile'.

Anyone knows a good step-by-step tutorial to learn how to create install profile starting from a production site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Developing installation profiles](http://drupal.org/node/159730) covers the majority of install profiles, well worth a look at to get started.

There is a how to guide [here](http://drupal.org/node/1022020) as well.

Answer (score 1):

While I think the drupal documentation is pretty good, I found this series of blog posts really helpful and easy to undestand.

http://scotthadfield.ca/2011/10/20/overview-d7-install-profiles

Answer (score 1):

This post really helped me get to grips with splitting down individual elements of profile config, such as setting up WYSIWYG options:

http://internetdevels.com/blog/drupal-7-install-profile